# Indy HTTP: Cannot change Host header

Tags: delphi, http, indy, indy10, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to change `Host` header before sending get request to a website. I do that using this code:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.HOST := 'example.com';
memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://stackoverflow.com');
showmessage(IdHTTP1.Request.Host); // Expected to be example.com but it's stackoverflow.com
```

I've got a big problem here. Even though I change `Host` header before getting URL, `Host` header will change to `stackoverflow.com` again. What am I doing wrong? I want to change request header to `example.com`.

Thanks

Comment: That field is being filled in the `TIdCustomHTTP.PrepareRequest` method. Anyway, why do you want to go against RFC 2616 standard saying about the host field *"The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the original URI given by the user or referring resource"* (that's exactly what Indy does when preparing request) ?

Comment: @TLama So is there anyways to stop `TIdCustomHTTP.PrepareRequest` from changing `Host` field? I want to access to a shared IP. So I need to specify `Host`. I need custom host because the host is not registered.

Comment: If the host is not DNS registered you can use the IP address directly: `http://w.x.y.z/`...

Comment: @mjn It's a shared IP. I cannot access to my desired page unless I have a custom Host property. The site show me a page only when I change `Host`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no option to specify a custom `Host` header that specifies a different hostname than the one specified in the URL.  The URL has priority.  Any hostname you specify in the `Request.Host` or even the `Request.CustomHeaders` is overwritten by the hostname in the URL.

If the hostname in the URL is not registered with DNS, you will not be able to reach it with *any* web browser, or most HTTP libraries including `TIdHTTP`.  While the HTTP protocol itself defines how the `Host` header works, current web browser technology uses the hostname from the URL, and so does `TIdHTTP`.  So it does not make sense to have a website that uses a hostname that is not registered with DNS in the first place, as most modern client systems would not be able to retrieve it.  DNS is required to convert the URL's hostname into an IP address, and then the same hostname is put into the `Host` header.

Comment: Actually it makes sense when you want to contact the server by IP, but connect to a specific virtual webserver, so HOSTNAME must be changed to correct domain. E.g. it's useful when one domain is associated with multiple IPs and we want to talk to specific instance (IP). One way is to modify "hosts" file, but not possible if must be done on client side.

Comment: @Niki in what situation would you want to do that in practice? Domains have multiple IPs all the time, it is used for load balancing, or directing international clients to nearby servers, etc, for instance. You shouldn't try to circumvent that manually. So what is your real use case here?

Comment: @Remi, in my case, I known that the servers that I am communicating with are not equal. They are supposed to be, but in that particular case, they are not. Probably the internal API is not upgraded everywhere to same versions. My API calls succeed on some IP,on other will fail.  That's way I want to be able to control it, at least temporarily, until the API is fixed server side. If everything was standard, our job will be so easier, and not always try to find workarounds stupid incompatibilities.

Comment: @Niki then you might consider using `TIdTCPClient` directly and implement the HTTP protocol manually so you have full control over how your requests are formed.

Comment: @Remy_Lebeau, I would prefer not, you know the story about killing a fly with dynamite...

Answer (score 0):

As Remy Lebeau said, it seems there is no way to specify a custom `Host` header. So I decided to modify `IdHTTP` codes just a little bit.

First I copied `IdHTTP.pas` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX.0\source\Indy10\Protocols\IdHTTP.pas`) to my project directory and added it to my project. Then in `TIdCustomHTTP.PrepareRequest`method (Line 1792) I changed the code like this:

```
if (TextIsSame(FURI.Protocol, 'http') and (FURI.Port = IntToStr(IdPORT_HTTP))) or  {do not localize}
      (TextIsSame(FURI.Protocol, 'https') and (FURI.Port = IntToStr(IdPORT_https))) then  {do not localize}
    begin
      if FURI.Host = 'stackoverflow.com' then
        ARequest.Host := 'example.com'
      else
        ARequest.Host := FURI.Host;
    end else begin
      if FURI.Host = 'stackoverflow.com' then
        ARequest.Host := 'example.com' + ':' + FURI.Port   {do not localize}
      else
        ARequest.Host := FURI.Host + ':' + FURI.Port;    {do not localize}
    end;
```

I know it's not the best way and modifying libraries is not a good idea but it worked for me.

So if I change the examples above, `stackoverflow.com` to `myblog.wordpress.com` and `example.com` to `anotherblog.wordpress.com`, By `IdHTTP1.Get('http://myblog.wordpress.com')` we will get `anotherblog.wordpress.com` content.

Comment: You could fire some sort of `OnRequestPrepared` event passing the prepared `ARequest` object e.g. right before the `TIdCustomHTTP.PrepareRequest` exits. In your application you would then write a handler for such event and additionally modify the request object. I mean [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/US4ZuNdB).